# Linq to sql - How to automatically capture user Id and update datetime on insert/update?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, data-access

I'm currently trying to find a better method of automatically capturing changes made when performing an insert or update.  We have a requirement to track the last datetime a record was changed as well as the userid of the user performing the update/insert.

Is there an elegant way to do this in linq to sql?  At the moment, we've added a Save method to all our (partial) classes that needs to be called, but this is causing problems because not all of our developers remember to use the Save method and are still using the context for their data access operations.

Also, we'd like to keep this logic out of the database, if we can help it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a save method on your partial classes, implement the OnValidate Method and set your properties there.

```
public partial class MyClass
{
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (action == System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction.Insert)
        {
            LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
            ChangedBy = "Me!";
        }

    }
}
```

This method is called automatically for you when the datacontext is submitted.

Comment: How would you get the User there?

Comment: Depends on your app. You said it was a web app so I'd imagine from the session

Comment: It's not my app. But usually linq to sql classes are in a data layer and do mot have access to the session...

Comment: Well you could always throw an exception in the OnValidate() method, thus if the developer does it wrong, that is not calling your save method, they will be told.